How to add a button to the "Collection" context menu?

I couldn't find anything in the blender files that would help me figure out how to do this. I would like to add a button so that it is the second in the list. Of all the attributes I found, COLLECTION_PT_collection_custom_props is the most similar to what I need, but when I create a button through it, nothing happens.

I found a way to do this. It requires using OUTLINER_MT_collection_new. However, I still haven't figured out how to place this button not at the beginning or end, but somewhere between the existing buttons.

Class OUTLINER_MT_collection_new is the right context menu for 'Scene Collection' (not for user collections). The class is part of space_outliner.py and can be found in C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender [Version][Version]\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_outliner.py (Windows example path).
The first two entries "New Collection" and "Paste Data-Blocks" are drawn by a function decorated as staticmethod. Static method objects cannot be changed, as the name implies.

But we can re-register the class with a modified staticmethod (tested 3.6.7, 4.1.1):
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu

# import classes
from bl_ui.space_outliner import OUTLINER_MT_collection_new  
from bl_ui.space_outliner import OUTLINER_MT_context_menu

original_class = OUTLINER_MT_collection_new  # store original to reset

# changed class
class OUTLINER_MT_collection_new(Menu): 
    bl_label = "Collection"
    @staticmethod
    def draw_without_context_menu(_context, layout):
        layout.operator("outliner.collection_new", text="New Collection").nested = True

        layout.label(text="* new *")   ### new entry

        layout.operator("outliner.id_paste", text="Paste Data-Blocks", icon='PASTEDOWN')

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        self.draw_without_context_menu(context, layout)
        layout.separator()
        OUTLINER_MT_context_menu.draw_common_operators(layout)

# overwrite class        
bpy.utils.register_class(OUTLINER_MT_collection_new)   

# reset class 
#bpy.utils.register_class(original_class) 


